# Redirect on panel page a nuisance! :)

Tags: views, panels, comments, redirection

I have a comment form on a panel and a view below it to display the posted comments. I wonder if there is a way, after posting a comment, to keep the viewer on the the same panel page without being redirected to the comment page? The behavior would be like posting the comment with ajax. Thanks. :)

Comment: Do you need the comment view to be updated also, or do you just not want the page to refresh/redirect?

Comment: I have set the comment view with ajax on. So that should refresh it (hopefully!) What I need is for the user not to be redirected to the comment page after he leaves the comment but stay on the panel page (the page where he left the comment.) Even if there is a refresh of the panel page :)

Comment: Have you looked at the ajax module? It ajaxifies all your forms.

Comment: Superb! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you. That takes care of the form. Do you also happen to know of a module that would instantly refresh the view that displays the comments? (it's a pane in a panel and Ajax is enabled in the view but does not refresh.)

Comment: There is [Ajax Views Refresh](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_views_refresh) but there is no D7 version, your tags don't say which version you're using.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Unfortunately, I use D7. Thanks. :)